# Laravel - Mysql to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

At the moment I have a list of employees as a json file.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "departments": "1",
    "name": "Bill Smith",
    "profilePic": "/img/people/Office/bill-smith.jpg",
    "title": "Office Manager"
  },
```

I now want to store these in the database but still return them as JSON.

How do I set this up with my routes? It will be a very basic filter, by department id.

I presume I would do a get request

```
Route::get('people/{department}', function () {

});
```

How do I return the json?

Comment: Laravel automatically converts array responses into JSON. just return an array from your route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have list of employees in a json file then First create a DB Seed to store your data in the DATABASE from that particular json file with the help of [Seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding).

Lets say you made a table departments in the database and stored your data in all 5 columns`(id, departments, name, profilePic, title)`, Then make a model that with the following command

```
php artisan make:model Department
```

For more details about models please visits on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Then simple detect that request through route and return the data as json:

```
Route::get('people/{department}', function ($departmentId) {
     $data = Department::where('departments', $departmentId)->first();
     return response()->json($data);
});
```

Comment: why `first()` this will return only one employee but a department may have multiple employees. It should be `get()` which return all employee within the selected department

Comment: @AbuSayem yes ofcuase he can use use `get()`, my main point is to tell him the right way, its depends on the him what he want, `get()` or `first()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `Employee` model, it would look like this:

```
Route::get('people/{department}', function ($departmentId) {
    return Employee::where('department_id', $departmentId)->get();
});
```

Laravel converts objects to JSON before writing them to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The very basic model query would be

`Route::get('people/{department}', function ($department) {
     return Employee::where('departments',$department)->get();
}`

> assume Employee is your model

.

Then Laravel automatically will convert your query to json.

**FYI:** You can also send this request to controller method the return like above